# aws + boto list of eips

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

Having a problem using boto to list any Elastic IPs.  So far, have been pretty successful in getting back a list of instances, and performing certain operations with them.
  However, not really sure how to get a list/dictionary back of all eips allocated...

I see the following object: cl = botoEC2.get_all_addresses, which does not seem to return much interesting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_all_addresses` works for me. It returns a list of address objects which have various methods and attributes.

```
addrs = conn.get_all_addresses()
for a in addrs:
    print a.public_ip
```

Prints out all the eips, associated and not associated, that I have on my account.

When I'm trying to figure out the AWS api I always fire up an IPython shell and put their tab completion to good use. It's great for finding your way around.

Comment: We do have fairly decent API docs, too.  See http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_all_addresses.  Always room for improvement, of course, but lots of info there.  But I usually use the IPython approach, too.

Comment: Your docs are fine! But I just find it easier to play directly with a live connection. Nothing beats playing with something to see exactly how it works.

Comment: Guys,  tab completion does not seem to be available inside a for loop in ipython...  Do you guys first write out the for loop?  or how do you get the actual objects?

Comment: Well, to get an object from a list just do `a = addrs[0]`. Then you can inspect `a`.

Comment: Hello, sorry, Is the solution above possible with IAM user credentials?

Comment: As long as the IAM user has the relevant permissions. Then yes. It should work. You'll get quite elaborate error messages as well